# VHDL code for register, to use in a binary multiplication circuit

Tags: syntax, vhdl, cpu-registers, binary-logic

I wrote a piece a VHDL code for a register (to make a shift register circuit) in a binary multiplication circuit. Once I analyzed it in Quartus II several syntax errors were displayed.

This is my code:

```
ENTITY memory IS
PORT (can_load, can_shift, can_ad, sb_input, ab_input, UserInput : IN BIT;
        Out_Bit, Z : OUT BIT);
END memory; 

ARCHITECTURE logic OF memory IS
    SIGNAL State: BIT := '0';
    BEGIN
        IF (can_load = '1') THEN
            State <= UserInput;
        ELSE
            IF (can_ad = '1') THEN
                Z <= State; --Z is the output that goes to the 4 bit adder
                State <= ab_input;
            END IF;
            IF (can_shift = '1') THEN
                Out_Bit <= State;
                State <= sb_input;
            END IF;
        END IF;
END logic;
```

These are the error messages:

Info: *******************************************************************

Info: Running Quartus II 64-Bit Analysis & Synthesis
    Info: Version 14.0.0 Build 200 06/17/2014 SJ Web Edition
    Info: Processing started: Sun Oct 19 16:28:22 2014
    Info: Version 14.0.0 Build 200 06/17/2014 SJ Web Edition
    Info: Processing started: Sun Oct 19 16:28:22 2014

Info: Command: quartus_map --read_settings_files=on --write_settings_files=off memory -c memory

Warning (20028): Parallel compilation is not licensed and has been disabled

Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at memory.vhd(9) near text "IF";  expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("if" is a reserved keyword), or a concurrent statement

Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at memory.vhd(9) near text "THEN";  expecting "<="

Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at memory.vhd(11) near text "ELSE";  expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("else" is a reserved keyword), or a concurrent statement

Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at memory.vhd(12) near text "THEN";  expecting "<="

Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at memory.vhd(15) near text "IF";  expecting ";", or an identifier ("if" is a reserved keyword), or "architecture"

Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at memory.vhd(16) near text "THEN";  expecting "<="

Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at memory.vhd(19) near text "IF";  expecting ";", or an identifier ("if" is a reserved keyword), or "architecture"

Info (12021): Found 0 design units, including 0 entities, in source file memory.vhd

I have already checked several books for the correct syntax, and code examples and yet I cannot find where's my mistake.

I also tried to take away the parentheses in sections like this:

```
IF (can_load = '1') THEN
```

having something like this:

```
IF can_load = '1' THEN
```

but I ended up with most of the same syntax errors.

I'd appreciate any help to solve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: IF ...THEN is a sequential statement. You are using it in the parallel processing region of an architecture. Use it in a process inside the architecture.

Comment: Thank you, I did it and it worked. I had no clue I couldn't use IF...THEN outside a process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a different tool to demonstrate the errors:

> ghdl -a memory.vhdl
>   memory.vhdl:9:9: a generate statement must have a label
>   memory.vhdl:9:29: 'generate' is expected instead of 'then'
>   ghdl: compilation error

Note the analyzer is complaining about a generate statement.  This is because an if statement is a sequential statement only found in a process or other concurrent statement or in a subprogram.

A generate statement with an conditional scheme (hence the `if`) is a concurrent process statement and requires a label.

Putting the if statement in a process:

```
entity memory is
port (can_load, can_shift, can_ad, sb_input, ab_input, userinput : in bit;
        out_bit, z : out bit);
end memory; 

architecture logic of memory is
    signal state: bit := '0';
begin
SOME_PROCESS:
    process (userinput, ab_input, state, sb_input)
    begin
        if can_load = '1' then
            state <= userinput;
        else
            if can_ad = '1' then
                z <= state; --z is the output that goes to the 4 bit adder
                state <= ab_input;
            end if;
            if can_shift = '1' then
                out_bit <= state;
                state <= sb_input;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end logic;
```

Analyzes.

Note I added `userinput`, `ab_input`, `state`, and `sb_input` to the process sensitivity list (everything that showed up on the right hand side of an assignment).

The presence of `state` also brings up another point.  The new value of `state` is not available in the current simulation cycle.  In your example the value of `out_bit` would be the value of `state` found before the process is executed.

And in most cases the parentheses in an if statement condition are superfluous. Parentheses are required for cases when the left right evaluation order isn't sufficient to determine the correct meaning (e.g. mixing `and` and `or` operators), operators are functions, and functions are expressions.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is really helpful. I'll make sure to take into account all of your advice. :)